# Avoiding Akka HTTP IO-TCP registration failures

Tags: akka, akka-http

I occasionally receive the following messages when starting my app. When I do, the app fails to initialise.

```
Unhandled: DeadLetter(
  Register(Actor[akka://myapp/user/StreamSupervisor-0/$$7#141722842],true,false),
  Actor[akka://myapp/user/StreamSupervisor-0/$$7#141722842],
  Actor[akka://myapp/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/59#87610191]
)
```

From [this old spray thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/1E0fs_QUe8k), I would guess that Akka system was not accepting TCP listener registration messages from Akka HTTP.

The error doesn't always happen when the application starts, making me think it's a timing issue.

I'm using

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.9",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % "2.5.11",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-tools" % "2.5.11",
"com.lightbend.akka" %% "akka-stream-alpakka-amqp" % "0.17",
```

What's actually going on, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: "You cannot rely upon message delivery guarantees when it comes to required resource cleanup."
https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/19222